# Are there any problems with using jagged-arrays in Fortran with multiple levels of allocation?

Tags: fortran, allocation, jagged-arrays

In my Fortran code, I want to use jagged arrays with multiple levels of allocation.  An example code of what I mean is

```
module nonsquare_matrix_mod
implicit none

   type :: nonsquare_matrix 
      integer :: d
      real*8, dimension(:), allocatable :: vector
   end type nonsquare_matrix

   type(nonsquare_matrix),dimension(:),allocatable :: mymatrix

end module nonsquare_matrix_mod

program nonsquare_matrix_test
   use nonsquare_matrix_mod
   implicit none

integer, parameter :: max_size=50
integer :: i

allocate(mymatrix(max_size))
do i=1,max_size
    allocate(mymatrix(i) % vector(i))
end do

print *, "allocated"


end program
```

I want to implement this programming strategy in order to conserve memory.  I know the memory saved in this example isn't too large, but for my actual project, I'm working with much larger data structures.  I was wondering if there are any dangers with this programming practice, such as data not being stored contiguously or being more prone to memory leaks.  Or is this a useful way of saving memory without many drawbacks?  Thanks.

Comment: Looks good to me, and I used this approach in the past. How much memory you save will depend on the array length variation between arrays. Best is to first write the code that is most intuitive to you. I would not worry about memory leaks as long as you stay away from pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using allocatable arrays only, you won't have any memory leak as it could be the case when using pointers. Whether the jagged array is a reasonable solution for your problem depends very much on the structure of your data. A few points to be noted:

- Your array won't be contigous, indeed. That has several implication, like worse caching behaviour, when you are accessing subsequent lines.
- You have to allocate every line via `allocate` individually. If it happens very often (e.g. inside a loop), that could be a problem, as allocation is a rather "slow" operation.
- If the lines in your array are really very different in size (and you do not have too many lines), you may save some considerable amount of memory.

If the length of the lines is set at the time of their creation and not changed afterwards (and you have a good guess of maximally how much elements you will have in your entire array), you could allocate a large buffer array, where you put in the lines, and an index array which contains the position of the first element of that line in the buffer array:

```
 program nonsquare_matrix_test
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
  integer, parameter :: maxlines = 50
  integer, parameter :: maxelements = 5000
  real(dp), allocatable :: buffer(:)
  integer, allocatable :: rowindex(:)
  integer :: ii

  allocate(buffer(maxelements))
  allocate(rowindex(maxlines + 1))
  rowindex(1) = 1
  do ii = 1, maxlines
    rowindex(ii + 1)  = rowindex(ii) + ii
  end do
  ! ...  
  ! Omitting the part which fills up the array
  ! ...
  ! Accessing a given line (e.g. line 5)
  print *, "Content of line 5:"
  print *, buffer(rowindex(5):rowindex(6)-1)

end program nonsquare_matrix_test
```